# code sign Application with non Apple certificate

Tags: macos, cocoa, code-signing-certificate

I want to share a free application containing an helper tool (that perform privileged tasks), but I need a certificate. To test the application I created a self-signed certificate, but this does not work in other OSes that are not mine. Of course it will never be published on the App Store!
The question is:
is there a way to be able to sign the application without Developper ID by Apple, and make the application working for all?

Comment: did you figure this out? were you able to sign an app with a non apple certificate? I'm looking to use this for app integrity.

Comment: Sure, just use the keychain Access utility